# Prevent SQL queries from appearing in my logging

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog

I am using Serilog for logging in my console application. I set it up as follows.

```
// Build configuration
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(ApplicationInfo.DataPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, false)
    .Build();

// Configure Serilog
string logFormat = "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt}][{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}";
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Verbose, logFormat)
    .WriteTo.File(ApplicationInfo.GetDataFileName("log"), LogEventLevel.Verbose, logFormat)
    .CreateLogger();

AppHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddDbContext<TTApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        });
        services.Configure<EmailSettings>(configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));
        services.Configure<SftpSettings>(configuration.GetSection("FtpSettings"));
    })
    .UseSerilog()
    .Build();
```

And in my *appsettings.json* file.

```
"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

This is working fine except that the SQL queries are showing up in my log apparently, related to Entity Framework exceptions.

I do not want to change the *log level*. I want to get logging for these errors. I just don't want the actual SQL queries included. It's not even a matter of security. They are just too verbose and make it hard to find the actual errors.

In my ASP.NET Core applications, I must add the following line to enable SQL queries in logging.

```
builder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
```

I need the opposite of this for my console application.

*Note: Please don't be too quick to mark as duplicate. I found similar questions, but couldn't find any that directly answered what I'm asking.*

Comment: You could add environment check if debug then add builder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging() if it's in release or production it won't add this info, since debugging will be only for the developer !

Comment: @khaledDehia: You misread the question. I don't want `EnableSensitiveDataLogging()`. I want the opposite of that.

Comment: thanks for clarifying, btw I meant development environment not debugging , my bad

Comment: Which Serilog extensions are you using?

Comment: @TiesonT.: It's all in my code. The second block is where I configure Serilog.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason my mind confused Serilog with MiniProfiler, and I was expecting to see explicit configuration for EF.

Comment: Could you perhaps include an example of one of the problem events, as JSON, using `WriteTo.Console(new CompactJsonFormatter())`? Need this info to be able to suggest an answer (there are a few options).

Answer (score 0):

You may filter the particular namespace that generates SQL commands and override

```
// Configure Serilog
string logFormat = "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt}][{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}";
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Verbose, logFormat)
    .WriteTo.File(ApplicationInfo.GetDataFileName("log"), LogEventLevel.Verbose, logFormat)
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose().MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Verbose().MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Query", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: This just blocks the logging from that source. As indicated in my question, I still want to know about the exception. I just don't want all of the SQL queries.

Comment: I've updated the answer to your need. You will need to overwrite the Verbose minimum level ...

Comment: Again, I still want the exceptions. So I don't want to change the exception filter.

Comment: The updated answer is exactly what it is, it will hide sql statement in normal situation, but will display when there is warning, error , fatal situation . It's not hiding all output. Try and see the output.